# curios vs curious

Tags: orthography

Is the spelling "curios" acceptable? Someone has given the title "The curios case of ..." for his talk (it does not follow by Benjamin Button!). At first, I thought that it is a misspell but after some googling, I am in doubt (there are 18,100 results for "curios case" found by Google, for instance, I found [https://www.amazon.com/Curios-case-Benjamin-Button/dp/1976249821](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1976249821)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Curios' would the plural form of 'curio', a curio being an object of, usually historical, significance. If you want to know what is going down you are 'curious'. I think it must have been a typo.

Comment: Amazon also has same book with the correct spelling (https://www.amazon.com/Curious-Case-Benjamin-Button/dp/1516896815/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1526795600&sr=1-1&dpID=51xYBQQisbL&preST=_SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch) There's something odd about the book linked to in the question. Not only does it have that typo, but the title puts "case" in lowercase, and it only lists it at 28 pages. (The book with the correctly spelled title has 84 pages.)

Comment: This is one where spell check can't help you, both are valid words, however with vastly different meanings ;)